# MuleSoft: Your application will not run due to vCore availability

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio

This is super frustrating, I just followed the video in training and created an account, In accessmanagement the sandbox shows 1 vCore, but when I deploy the application it say, "Your application will not run due to vCore availability", still if I go ahead and deploy which it allows, it says "The maximum number(0) of live sandbox applications has been reached."

whats going on here, I have read similar blogs and questions here, this is probably going to be considered as duplicate, but none of existing questions help.

I am using training account and there is no Dev just sandbox environment, so don't tell me to go to Test environment, as all I find is sandbox environment there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I fixed it myself, on deployment window in anypoint studio, top right hand corner, if allows you to select group that you have created under organisation.

Select group that has vCore assigned and it will get deployed.

Answer (score 2):

change vCore to 0.1vCore. As trial account only allows 1 vCore. With 0.1 vCore you can deploy 10 applications.

Comment: I tried that, that was the first suggestions my colleagues here gave, but it did not work, before deploying itself it has a message under the core's dropdown that 'mulesoft-your-application-will-not-run-due-to-vcore-availability', how does it know that I have no cores, when in the subscription it shows 1 vcore for sandbox/test environment.

Answer (score 0):

My trail account was setup with availability in Production and not Sandbox.

I followed the instructions in [this link](https://medium.com/pacroy/mulesoft-u-development-fundamentals-week-3-cad56dde110c) and added a new environment using production and it all seemed to work out.